# Turn off image captions in gallery view?

Tags: images, shortcode, gallery, captions

I've set up my loop-attachment.php to show the gallery of thumbnails above the main, selected image using this code from the WordPress Codex:

```
<?php
    $gallery_shortcode = '[gallery id="' . intval( $post->post_parent ) . '" size="mini-thumbnail" columns="10"]';
    print apply_filters( 'the_content', $gallery_shortcode );
?>
```

However, if the image has a caption, it shows up underneath its image, throwing off my neat little grid of images. I don't want to turn captions completely off or not use them at all, because after the grid and below the main 960x540 image, I want to do an "Image Summary" kind of section, with the filename, original size, caption, description, etc.

Is there a way to turn off captions in the above code? The gallery shortcode section of the WordPress Codex doesn't have anything on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can always just set a css tag `display:none` to the caption element

Comment: Yep, I'm an idiot lol. Works just fine. For those wondering, you can just display:none on the "wp-caption-text" OR "gallery-caption" classes. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Or you can dynamically do it by jquery - may be do it on some condition

```
( function( $ ) {    
    //you can put this line of code after some condition function
     $( '.gallery-caption').css({display:'none'});

} )( jQuery );
```